# C# Generic methods and Calling way

Tags: c#, generics, generic-list

```
static List<T> GetInitializedList<T>(T value, int count)
{ 
    List<T> list = new List<T>();   

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
       list.Add(value); 
    }
    return list;
}
```

Above displayed generic methods can be called as follows...

EX-1

```
List<bool> list1 = GetInitializedList(true, 5);
```

EX-2

```
List<string> list2 = GetInitializedList<string>("Perls", 3);
```

I want know about the difference between calling this generic methods using the EX-1 and EX-2

what is the most efficient /standard / best way of calling the genric method.

EX-1 or EX-2

Answer (score 7):

They're equivalent. Basically, if you don't specify the *type arguments* to the method (i.e. the types in the `<>` in the method invocation), the compiler will try to use *type inference* to work out which type arguments you meant, based on the *actual* arguments (the expressions in the `()` in the method invocation).

They compile to *exactly* the same code, when the compiler infers the type arguments you wanted. In some cases you need to specify type arguments if:

- The type can't be inferred by the compiler. Example:

  ```
  GetInitializedList<string>(null, 5);
  ```

  Here the compiler can't infer the type argument because `null` has no type.
- The type that the compiler would infer isn't what you want. Example:

  ```
  List<object> objects = GetInitializedList<object>("foo", 5);
  ```

  Here the compiler would infer a type argument of `string`, which isn't what we want.

Comment: It turns out even if I read C# in depth and provide an answer before Jon Skeet. He still gets all the up-votes :)

Comment: @user3185569 even Chuck Norris can't provide a better scoring answer than Jon Skeet.

Answer (score 2):

No difference, the second way has a redundant specified type. The compiler already tries infers the type from the parameters.

When you write:

```
List<string> list2 = GetInitializedList("Perls", 3);
```

The compiler infers that T is string because type of parameter `value` is string.

In latest versions of Visual Studio, the IDE advises you to remove `<string>` if the compiler was able to infer the type.

Unless the compiler can't infer the type, you don't need to use the second approach. Example:

```
public void GenericMethod<T>()
{

}
```

Here you are force to specify the type since there are no parameters from which the compiler can infer the type.

This will not compile:

```
GenericMethod();
```

This will compile:

```
GenericMethod<string>();
```

There are other cases where the compiler can't infer the type. So you must explicitly specify it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, what you really have in both cases is the latter version.

The first one is only possible because of the compiler **inferring** the generic argument which means that although the parameter is omitted, the compiler acts like the parameter is there.